# Java OpenCV Error: Assertion failed

Tags: java, swing, opencv, cascade-classifier

I need a little help with why am I getting this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (clEnqueueReadBuffer(q, (cl_mem)u->handle, CL_TRUE, 0, u->size, alignedPtr.getAlignedPtr(), 0, 0, 0) == CL_SUCCESS) in cv::ocl::OpenCLAllocator::map, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\ocl.cpp, line 3961
Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\ocl.cpp:3961: error: (-215) clEnqueueReadBuffer(q, (cl_mem)u->handle, CL_TRUE, 0, u->size, alignedPtr.getAlignedPtr(), 0, 0, 0) == CL_SUCCESS in function cv::ocl::OpenCLAllocator::map
]
    at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(CascadeClassifier.java:176)
    at test.processor.detect(window.java:66)
    at test.window.main(window.java:100)
```

I tried googling and came up with no good solutions. I did set OpenCV in the buildpath and everything, plus it loads the frontalface.xml which some say might be the problem.

When running is starts the JPanel and then the error comes up at this line in code:

```
face_cascade.detectMultiScale(mGrey, faces);
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

```
package test;

 /*  
  * Captures the camera stream with OpenCV  
  * Search for the faces  
  * Display a circle around the faces using Java
  */  
 import java.awt.*;  
 import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;  
 import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;  
 import javax.swing.*;  
 import org.opencv.core.Mat;  
 import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;  
 import org.opencv.core.Point;  
 import org.opencv.core.Rect;  
 import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;  
 import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;  
 import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;  
 class My_Panel extends JPanel{  
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  
      private BufferedImage image;  
      // Create a constructor method  
      public My_Panel(){  
           super();   
      }  
      /**  
       * Converts/writes a Mat into a BufferedImage.  
       *   
       * @param matrix Mat of type CV_8UC3 or CV_8UC1  
       * @return BufferedImage of type TYPE_3BYTE_BGR or TYPE_BYTE_GRAY  
       */  
      public boolean MatToBufferedImage(Mat matBGR){  
           long startTime = System.nanoTime();  
           int width = matBGR.width(), height = matBGR.height(), channels = matBGR.channels() ;  
           byte[] sourcePixels = new byte[width * height * channels];  
           matBGR.get(0, 0, sourcePixels);  
           // create new image and get reference to backing data  
           image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);  
           final byte[] targetPixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();  
           System.arraycopy(sourcePixels, 0, targetPixels, 0, sourcePixels.length);  
           long endTime = System.nanoTime();  
           System.out.println(String.format("Elapsed time: %.2f ms", (float)(endTime - startTime)/1000000));  
           return true;  
      }  
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g){  
           super.paintComponent(g);   
           if (this.image==null) return;  
            g.drawImage(this.image,10,10,this.image.getWidth(),this.image.getHeight(), null);  
           //g.drawString("This is my custom Panel!",10,20);  
      }  
 }  
 class processor {  
      private CascadeClassifier face_cascade;  
      // Create a constructor method  
      public processor(){  
           face_cascade=new CascadeClassifier("C:\\Users\\Kladnik\\Downloads\\opencv\\sources\\data\\lbpcascades\\lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");  
      }  
      public Mat detect(Mat inputframe){  
           Mat mRgba=new Mat();  
           Mat mGrey=new Mat();  
           MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();  
           inputframe.copyTo(mRgba);  
           inputframe.copyTo(mGrey);  
           Imgproc.cvtColor( mRgba, mGrey, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);  
           Imgproc.equalizeHist( mGrey, mGrey );  
           face_cascade.detectMultiScale(mGrey, faces);  
           System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces", faces.toArray().length));  
           for(Rect rect:faces.toArray())  
           {  
                Point center= new Point(rect.x + rect.width*0.5, rect.y + rect.height*0.5 );  
                //Core.ellipse( mRgba, center, new Size( rect.width*0.5, rect.height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, new Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );  
           }  
           return mRgba;  
      }  
 }  
 public class window {  
      public static void main(String arg[]){  
       // Load the native library.  
       System.loadLibrary("opencv_java300");       
       String window_name = "Capture - Face detection";  
       JFrame frame = new JFrame(window_name);  
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    frame.setSize(400,400);  
    processor my_processor=new processor();  
    My_Panel my_panel = new My_Panel();  
    frame.setContentPane(my_panel);       
    frame.setVisible(true);        
       //-- 2. Read the video stream  
        Mat webcam_image=new Mat();  
        VideoCapture capture =new VideoCapture(0);   
    if( capture.isOpened())  
           {  
            while( true )  
            {  
                 capture.read(webcam_image);  
              if( !webcam_image.empty() )  
               {   
                    frame.setSize(webcam_image.width()+40,webcam_image.height()+60);  
                    //-- 3. Apply the classifier to the captured image  
                    webcam_image=my_processor.detect(webcam_image);  
                   //-- 4. Display the image  
                    my_panel.MatToBufferedImage(webcam_image); // We could look at the error...  
                    my_panel.repaint();   
               }  
               else  
               {   
                    System.out.println(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!");   
                    break;   
               }  
              }  
             }  
             return;  
      }  
 }
```

Comment: I just want to mention that OpenCV loads an image in the BGR format, so just do a BGR2GRAY. It is not the error that you are meeting there, but it is an error that should be corrected.

Comment: I do not see and error in your code... So just try to load another xml, I am sure that there are more (for example, does haar classifier work?).

Comment: @sop we used this one in school and it worked ok, but none the less, I will give it a try

Comment: I did not verify if the xmls from OpenCV 2.4 are different from the ones of OpenCV 3.0.0, Maybe it is a problem of versions, is you have passed to version 3?